# I m very much confused seeing a statement of Map in flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

I am following a tutor channel..almost going we'll but confused at a statement

there is a provider class named cart.. and as we know,,, cart contains more than one cart items...but in code...tutor has given `Map<String,CartItem> items={}` and I think he should take `List<Map<String,CartItem>> items=[];`

here is a code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class CartItem {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final int quantity;
  final double price;

  CartItem({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.quantity,
    @required this.price,
  });
}

class Cart with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, CartItem> _items = {};

  Map<String, CartItem> get items {
    return {..._items};
  }

  int get itemCount {
    return _items.length;
  }

  void addItem(
    String productId,
    double price,
    String title,
  ) {
    if (_items.containsKey(productId)) {
      // change quantity...
      _items.update(
        productId,
        (existingCartItem) => CartItem(
              id: existingCartItem.id,
              title: existingCartItem.title,
              price: existingCartItem.price,
              quantity: existingCartItem.quantity + 1,
            ),
      );
    } else {
      _items.putIfAbsent(
        productId,
        () => CartItem(
              id: DateTime.now().toString(),
              title: title,
              price: price,
              quantity: 1,
            ),
      );
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: I mean Map<String,CartItem> items={} is this showing array of map?

Comment: Why do you think that? What benefit would you get from having a list of those?

Comment: what is key of your Map?

Comment: Okay, Sir.. I got it now..why it is not taken as list<Map<>>

Comment: What's wrong to use  List<CartItem> items=[] instead of using map...